# SQL Server Compact Edition Data Access with the SqlCeResultSet in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce

I would like  use the SqlCeResultSet like this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb219485.aspx) in Visual Studio 2013.

This is the code of my class Form1:

```
private SqlCeConnection _conn;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Northwind.sdf");
            this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT [Employee ID], [Last Name], [First Name], Photo FROM Employees",_conn);
            SqlCeResultSet resultSet = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable | ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = resultSet;
        }
```

Now I try to follow exactly the tutorial with my Database and when execute the line:

```
 SqlCeResultSet resultSet = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable | ResultSetOptions.Updatable)
```

throw this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll Additional information:
>   ExecuteResultSet: Connection property has not been initialized.

For more details this is my Solution Explorer:

[image]

And I have installed:

[image]

Any idea or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Updating**

Maybe the problem is that SQL Server Compact is discontinued from Visual Studio 2013 see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363374/is-sql-server-compact-discontinued-from-visual-studio-2013). In this case exist any alternative for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed step 24 in the tutorial - you need to open the connection:

```
 SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT [Employee ID], [Last Name], [First Name], Photo FROM Employees",_conn);
 _conn.Open();
 SqlCeResultSet resultSet = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable | ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
 this.bindingSource1.DataSource = resultSet;
```